# Capturing Users Who Press Print Screen and Submitting User IP, Forum Name, Member ID, and the URL

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a script to Capturing Users Who Press Print Screen and when it's done so it will submit the following information:

MEMBER_ID, NAME, IP, DATE, URL

I would also like it to upload what they screened and uploaded it to imgur and have a link to that in the database as well.

I'm currently working on the script and this is what I have so far.

Could anyone please help me finish this or point me in the right direction :)

```
<script>
var afterPrint = function() {
     // Get member ID
                $ips_username = $this->request['ips_username'];
                $this->DB->build(array(
                    'select' => 'member_id',
                    'from'   => 'members',
                    'where'  => 'name = "' . $ips_username . '"'
                ));
                $this->DB->execute();
                $row = $this->DB->fetch();
                $member_id = $row['member_id'];

                // Get IP
                $ip = '';
                if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
                   // $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
                //else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
                    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP');
                else if(getenv('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'))
                    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP');
                else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
                    $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
                else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
                    $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
                else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
                   $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
                else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
                    $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
                else
                    $ip = 'UNKNOWN';       

                // Connect to logs database
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                    // New IP for member ID, insert new row
                    // Get current forum display name
                $this->DB->build(array(
                    'select' => 'members_display_name',
                    'from'   => 'members',
                    'where'  => 'member_id = ' . $member_id . ''
                ));
                $this->DB->execute();
                $row = $this->DB->fetch();
                $current_name = $row['members_display_name'];

                    mysqli_query($conn, 'insert into screenshot_logs(MEMBER_ID,NAME,IP,DATE,URL)
                   values(
                       ' . $member_id . ',
                       "' . $current_name . '",
                       "' . $ip . '",
                       NOW(),
                   );');
                } 

                //End screenshot tracking
};
```

Comment: Have you written php code inside javascipt ?

Comment: I would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help me figuring out why this isn't working :)

Comment: I'm confused by the syntax. Is this PHP? you start with a `<script>` tag and a `var` keyword to declare a variable suggesting Javascript, but the rest of the code seems to be PHP

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you are struggling with. We can't help you finish your code but we can help you understand why specific things may or may not be working.

Comment: Basically what i'm trying to do is capture when a user print screen can submit the current URL they are visiting, their member ID off of the IPB forums, their IP and the Date they did it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because it is neither valid JavaScript, nor valid PHP.  You start with a `<script>` tag and a JavaScript variable declaration `var afterPrint`, but you follow that up with `PHP` code.

> Could anyone please help me finish this or point me in the right
>   direction :)

PHP and JavaScript don't run in the same context. PHP is run on the server and has no idea what's happening on the browser. If a good solution to your problem existed, it would follow the design pattern below:

1. In JS, you register a listener for the `screenshot` event
2. User takes a screenshot
3. Your listener is triggered; it collects information about the browser context (user info, screenshot) and submits it to a PHP script.
4. In PHP, you record the IP address, the date, and the info submitted in your DB

The problem as I see it is that it is really difficult to reliably detect the screenshot in the first place.  It could be taken by an application that is completely separate from the browser, when the browser is not in focus. In that case the browser would have no idea a screenshot was taken and neither would your application.

The screenshot could even be taken with a camera pointed at the computer screen.  Preventing the user from saving what she sees in her browser cannot be done from within the browser.  I think you should take a step back and ask yourself: why am I doing this?  What am I ultimately trying to achieve? Another solution might present itself.

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent the user from using other programs etc. I just simply need to be able to capture a user when they press the print screen button or any variation of and submit their IP, Member ID out of the IPB Database, The data they pressed it, and the URL they are currently on. I don't mind paying someone to help me get this working. It's being implemented into an IPB Forum to look for spies who are trying to steal data of of the forum. I'm not trying to stop them from doing so or from using any programs. But if a user is dumb enough to print screen I would like to know.

Comment: So you're ok with people taken screenshots; you're not trying to prevent them but you just want to know when they printscreen?

Comment: BettleJuice your extra correct. That's is all i'm trying to do :) is it possible?

Comment: Basically what i'm trying to do is capture when a user print screen can submit the current URL they are visiting, their member ID off of the IPB forums, their IP and the Date they did it.

Comment: If you're willing to pay, you can hire me to do it, but what I said in my solution applies. Basically there is no way to reliably know when the user has taken a screenshot because your script lives inside the browser, and the screenshot can be taken when the browser is not in focus (meaning the browser cannot tell what the user is doing)